# Function that outputs winner based on value of a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a simple function that outputs the word "winner" if it lands on the value that is .05 or 5% chance. I have below as:

```
def spin():
    for x in range(50):
        rand = random.randint(1,21)
        if rand == 1:
            print("winner")
        else:
            print(rand)
```

where if you lets say spin a wheel gives you back the value winner if you land on 1/20 = .05 or 5%.

I want to tweak to below where instead of hardcoding the value 1, I just have the calculation as `rand / max(rand)` which should be the rand lets say 1 over the 20 max value but it gives me an error of

**TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable**

```
def spin():
        for x in range(100):
            rand = random.randint(1,21)
            rand = rand / max(rand)
            if rand == .05:
                print("winner")
            else:
                print(rand)
```

How can I do the above correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Could you not just use `if random.random() <= 0.05` and save worrying about calculating percentages?

Comment: Max works on iterables but not an int.

Comment: @JonClements would i put that random.random after my rand = random.randint(1,21) ? Thanks

Comment: @JonClements I didnt want the value to be less than or equal to .05 I wanted to to be only .05 or 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rand` is an integer. You're calling `max()` on a non-iterable (as opposed to a list/tuple/etc.).

If you're attempting to roll `n` times on a die/wheel/etc. that has a range of `1 to m`, and print/stop at the first 1, this should do it:

```
import random 

def spin(n, m):
    for x in range(n + 1):
        rand = random.randint(1, m)
        rand = rand / m
        if rand == 0.05:
            print(f"winner with {rand}")
            return
        else:
            print(rand)


spin(100, 20)
```

Please keep in mind this will only work for ‘n’ such that n * 0.05 is an integer. If you don't want to stop at the winner, just remove the `return`.

Comment: yeah but was trying to avoid hard coded numbers like 20

Comment: @Chris90 I edited my answer, but I think it would help if you defined a little better what the different numbers you're using represent.

Comment: Thanks, what does the m -= 1 ,mean or do? Thanks @chemicalwill

Comment: @Chris90 `-=` means subtract from itself. `m = m - 1` and `m -= 1` do the same thing, and works with almost all arithmetic operators

Comment: Also why is is range ( 100 + 1 ) instead of just (100 or n) ? Thanks

Comment: @Chris90 `range(x,y)` starts at/on `x` (default 1) and goes *up to but not including* `y`, for example `range(100)` would give you the numbers 1-99

Comment: Thanks, I understand that but I didnt see the 1, 101 only range(101) so i was confused @chemicalwill

Comment: When I add print(f'WINNER! with {rand}') instead of just winner = it gives me winner for wrong values such as .333333 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230653/discussion-between-chemicalwill-and-chris90).

Answer (score 2):

Your main issue is that the single argument form of `max` expects an iterable and an `int` isn't iterable... so `max([1, 2, 5, 4])` would work and the two form argument would work as well if given two `int`s, eg: `max(1, 7)`.

That'd being said:

I'd use `random.random` which returns a float between 0 and 1 (so you can think of that as a percentage in a way) and refactor your function to take arguments for the number of spins and the chance of winning, eg:

```
import random

def spin(spins, chance):
    for n in range(spins):
        rand = random.random()
        if rand <= chance:
            print(f'WINNER! with {rand}')
            # possibly return here if you don't need to continue spinning
        else:
            print(f'sorry - it was {rand}')
```

Then run it as:

```
spin(20, 1 / 20)
```

And that will print something similar to:

```
sorry - it was 0.18884703719033558
WINNER! with 0.014685074294810252
sorry - it was 0.4022748289267081
sorry - it was 0.42105107834994604
sorry - it was 0.6230194565583536
sorry - it was 0.6888109079338256
sorry - it was 0.3657541922937555
sorry - it was 0.8645435613279019
sorry - it was 0.0689853065211925
sorry - it was 0.30898761848279177
sorry - it was 0.2521114213641409
sorry - it was 0.4551206835668362
sorry - it was 0.9547685046007383
sorry - it was 0.895968162661857
sorry - it was 0.6074517146220099
sorry - it was 0.7386379650413437
sorry - it was 0.9736256214466487
sorry - it was 0.21999465453265188
sorry - it was 0.0727319509600649
sorry - it was 0.41137118714375376
```

Then you easily do other "odds", eg:

```
spin(50, 3 / 7)
```

Comment: Thank you, the only thing I dont follow is I want the winner to be exactly lets say odds of .05, why do you have if rand <= chance? shouldn't it be == chance? thnx @jonclements

Comment: @Chris90 I was reading what you were doing as odds of 1 in 20... and doing it that way makes it easier to do such odds... you can  use `spin(20, 1 / 2000)` where 1/2000 is a 0.05 chance of winning

Comment: @Chris90 note - you did say *or 5% chance* - which is 1/20 though... which the code above does... being exactly equal to 0.05 is equivalent to a 1/2000 chance

Comment: Yes thats correct I am new to pyhton so I thought the rand <= meant less than or equal to chance of .05? shouldn't it be only == to .05 chance?

Comment: I think this works but it does not give me the correct values for winner? I wanted it to say winner when it only .05 and nothing else, this seems to give me winner for different other values?

Comment: @Chris90 think of it this way... a chance of correctly calling a coin toss is 50%, right? If we generate a number between 0 and 1 and check that that number is exactly equal to 0.5 - that's not 50%... what we're doing here is treating anything between 0 and 0.5 (a win) as the range of numbers that is one of the 50%'s and anything 0.5 to 1 as the other (a loss)... so we've partitioned the win case into a range of numbers... your 5% chance of winning shown here is any number between 0 <= 0.05 (so it could be 0 or 0.37 or 4.9 etc...) and > 0.05 is considered a loss... does that make sense?

Comment: yes that makes sense, thank you, but what if I wanted to just have outputs that were just .05 only? Can I change the <= to ==, and where can I add a round to 2 decimal places to get that .05 output?

Comment: @Chris90 then change the <= to be == but it won't be 5% - in fact, as this uses floats, it'd be one in billions...

Comment: ah okay, i wanted to basically create a spin of  the wheel and to declare winner if I land at .05 or 5% exactly